# How to wrap the main page block

Tags: theming, 8

Back in Drupal 7 I never needed the `main_page_content` to be a block. Now that I am Working with Drupal 8 I need such a logic for the first time.

Is there a way to wrap the `main_page_content` into a block or any wrapper without wrapping the whole content region?